# Unable to launch app via appium capabilities but app launched successfully via 'xcrun simctl install booted install myApp.app'

Tags: automation, appium, ios-simulator, appium-ios

Error message: ‘myApp.app’ cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified.

I face above error when I install the myApp.app using Appium on my iOS simulator. However, when I install the same myApp.app using terminal command ‘xcrun simctl install booted install myApp.app’ then the app installed/launched perfectly fine.

Note: I am a tester hence I have not built the app using XCode and moving forward I will be getting the .app file only from the developer for testing.

Below are the details

- Appium desktop client version : 1.15.1
- macOS version : 10.15.2
- XCode version: 11.3

I am using below appium desired capabilities for iOS

```
{
“platformName”: “iOS”,
“platformVersion”: “13.3”,
“deviceName”: “iPhone 8”,
“automationName”: “XCUITest”,
“app”: “/Users/harj/Desktop/myApp.app”,
“bundleId”: “com.abc.xyzApp”,
“commandTimeouts”: 60000,
“noReset”: false,
“autoGrantPermissions”: true,
“useNewWDA”: true,
“showXcodeLog”: true
}
```

Appium logs
There are many errors in the log but i found this one relevent
Original error: ‘idb’ has not been found in PATH. Is it installed? Read https://www.fbidb.io for more details

That would be great if someone faced the same problem and got a solution.

Happpy Testing
harj

Comment: So are you using idb instead of WebdriverAgent?

Answer (score 0):

I can able to launch the sample .app file on simulator with below versions.

I have resolved setup issue for simulator 13.4 version with xcode 11.4.

```
Simulator-: 13.4

xcode    -: 11.4

mac os.  -: 10.15.4

appium v -: 1.17.0
```

If you still face any issue then let me know. with appium logs and whole details.

Comment: I have already tried this version of simulator but still facing the issue. 
Did you add developer certificates during WebDriverAgent setup in Xcode? Or it is not required?

Comment: @HarjeetSingh Yes we need to add Devloper certificate for particular app to install on simulator. For real device there is no need to add developer certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, the solution has been found. 
Actually, the problem is with the macOS Catalina not with the Appium. The OS was preventing the .app to install on the simulator. There are two ways to solve this problem.
1) Degrade the gatekeeper(security) check on your mac.
2) Quarantine that specific app using below terminal command

```
xattr -dr com.apple.quarantine /yourAppPath/myApp.app
```

I recommended the option2 as it will keep your mac safe from attacks.